# CSS: % sizes in width and height in menus with images

Tags: html, css, layout, scaling

I have a site which should be suitable for mobile visitors, and therefore should scale to the dimensions of the user's screen, both in width and height. Furthermore, I have 2 navigation menus (1 left, 1 right), and some fixed info on the bottom (like a footer). All these parts contain images that should be scaled to fit into the menu's dimensions. Concretely, the page is something like (adding a random image that is too big by default):

```
<body>
  <table class="wholepage">

    <tr class="top">

      <td class="left">
        <table>
          <tr><td><img src="http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/0304/bluemarble2k_big.jpg"/></td></tr>
          <tr><td><img src="http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/0304/bluemarble2k_big.jpg"/></td></tr>
        </table>
      </td>

      <td class="middle">Middle content</td>

      <td class="right">
        <table>
          <tr><td><img src="http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/0304/bluemarble2k_big.jpg"/></td></tr>
          <tr><td><img src="http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/0304/bluemarble2k_big.jpg"/></td></tr>
        </table>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="bottom">

      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/0304/bluemarble2k_big.jpg"/></td>
          <td><img src="http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/0304/bluemarble2k_big.jpg"/></td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.wholepage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wholepage img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.top {
  height: 80%;
}

.left, .right {
  width: 15%;
}

.middle {
  width: 70%;
}

.bottom {
  height: 20%;
}
```

Like that, the width of the page adapts itself perfectly, sticking to the 15%-70%-15% distribution between left-middle-right. However, vertically, all the images refuse to scale. How can I get the page to fit to the 80%-20% distribution for top-bottom?

EDIT: Here's a way to see it, if you fill this in in http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_default

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wholepage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wholepage img {
  width: 100%;
}

.top {
  height: 80%;
}

.left, .right {
  width: 15%;
}

.left {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.right {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.middle {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.bottom {
  height: 20%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wholepage">

    <div class="top">

      <div class="left">
        <table>
          <tr><td><img src="http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/0304/bluemarble2k_big.jpg" /></td></tr>
          <tr><td><img src="http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/0304/bluemarble2k_big.jpg" /></td></tr>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div class="middle">Middle content</div>

      <div class="right">
        <table>
          <tr><td><img src="http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/0304/bluemarble2k_big.jpg" /></td></tr>
          <tr><td><img src="http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/0304/bluemarble2k_big.jpg" /></td></tr>
        </table>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="bottom">

      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/0304/bluemarble2k_big.jpg"/></td>
          <td><img src="http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/0304/bluemarble2k_big.jpg"/></td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up hacking it. Unless someone knows a better way, here's what I did:

```
function fixHorizontalDimension(){
  maxHeight = window.innerHeight * [% height desired] * 0.9;
  imgs = document.getElementsByClassName([classname of wrongly sized objects]);
  for(i=0; i<imgs.length; i++){
    imgs[i].style.height = maxHeight;
  }
}
```

Since the site is only to be used personally, and using a mobile browser, this fix does the job. Resizing (e.g. switching from portrait to landscape) doesn't work though.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use width & height, just use max-width:

```
.wholepage img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

IE < 8 scales images poorly and to get good quality scaling you need to use `AlphaImageLoader` with the `SizingMethod` set to `scale`. Probably the easiest way to do that is with [Drew Diller's DD_BelatedPNG library](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/). Be aware there are performance implications to using the `AlphaImageLoader`. Also, IE6 doesn't support `max-width` so use `width: 100%` in a conditional comment if you need to support IE6.

Also, I can say enough about [Ethan Marcotte's A List Apart Article on Responsive Design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/) (which is an excerpt from also excellent his book.)

Comment: max-width doesn't do it .. I'm using firefox for now, and move to IE when I've got at least 1 browser working. I've added some hopefully useful way to see it for yourself in my question.

Answer (score 0):

First; don't use tables for styling. Use divs, or even better the html5 tags like `<header>` and `<footer>` and such.

To ensure correct handling of height with percentages, you should set html and body to 100% height as well, like:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

Comment: Point taken, but setting the html/body height to 100% still doesn't scale the images vertically.

Comment: Try giving the images an attribute `height="100%"` and/or css property `img { height: 100%; }`.

Comment: That's in the CSS I posted: `.wholepage img { width: 100%; height: 100%; }`

Comment: Hm, and the attributes don't do it either? If you set bg colors, how do these fill?

Comment: They fill horizontally like expected (15-70-15), vertically I get a scroller for the whole page, and a (much too) big coloured footer at the bottom.

Comment: I changed it to div's and added a pastable entry for the w3schools editor. Still the same result, though.

Comment: I'd recommend switching to divs later, after this is fixed. When setting html and body height to 100%, make sure you set margin and padding to 0 on both of them. Often they have several pixels margin/padding by default, resulting in scrollbars.